# Outlook emails from VB application stuck during send until Outlook is manually opened

Tags: vba, email, outlook, office365

I have an older Visual Basic 6 application that sends emails by connecting to the Outlook.Application object for Outlook Automation.  The Outlook we use is Outlook 365.  We run the VB application on two separate PC's.  Both PC's are Windows 10.

Outlook is shut down when the VB application creates and sends the email.

On one PC, the emails get sent and received within a minute.

On the other PC, the emails are held up until Outlook is manually opened.

Does anyone have any advice/ideas why one doesnt need Outlook running to send emails while the other one does?

I've tried to Outlook open all the time when sending the emails, but I receive an error on the VB application that there is a conflict.

Comment: Have you tries to compare profile settings in Outlook? Do they use different connection settings with Exchange Online?

Comment: What code exactly do you use for sending emails? What conflict exactly do you see?

Comment: yes, profiles are identical. Nothing I can see different.

Comment: Code is below (streamlined)

Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If olApp Is Nothing Then
        Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
        blRunning = False
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
     ls_DestinationAddr = Trim(ls_DestinationAddr)
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With olMail
        .Subject = ls_Subject

        .Recipients.Add ls_DestinationAddr

        .HTMLBody = ls_Body
        
        .Send
        
    End With

Comment: Try to use the `SendAndReceive` method and wait the `SyncEnd` event before closing Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

In the cached mode, emails are not sent immediately - message submission is always an asynchronous process, and if you close Outlook while the messages are still being submitted, they won't be sent.

A couple options:

1. Turn Exchange cached mode off. In that case it will be the Exchange server sending emails, not Outlook, and the message will taken over by Exchange even if Outlook is immediately closed.
2. Call [Namespace.SendAndReceive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.sendandreceive) and wait for the [SyncObject.SyncEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobject.syncend) (where `SyncObject` is the first item in the `Namespace.SyncObjects` collection - "All Accounts") event to fire before closing Outlook.

Comment: Outlook isnt open.  The VBA connects to the Outlook object and sends the email.  But the email isnt received.  I then open Outlook on the PC and thats when it sends.

Comment: Yes, the two workarounds above would work just fine in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have any advice/ideas why one doesn't need Outlook running to send emails while the other one does?

It *depends* on how Outlook is connected with Exchange Online - whether the message is processed locally or the online mode is used in Outlook where the item is sent out from Exchange directly, i.e. how Outlook communicates with the server-side represented by the Exchange server. So, I'd start from checking the Outlook connection settings.

Another possible reason is Outlook settings like shown on the picture:

[image: Send emails immediately setting in Outlook]

This setting is tied to the following registry data, so this setting can also be configured by an administrator through a modification of the registry.

```
Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office<x.0>\Outlook\Options\Mail
```

or

```
Policy key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office<x.0>\Outlook\Options\Mail
```

The key has the following name and value:

```
DWORD: Send Mail Immediately
Value: 0
```

Read more about that in the [Email stays in the Outbox folder until you manually initiate a send/receive operation in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/synchronization/email-stays-in-outbox-until-manually-send-or-receive) article.

The Outlook object model provides the `SendAndReceive` method which provides the programmatic equivalent to the `Send/Receive All` command that is available when you click `Tools` and then `Send/Receive`.

If you don't need to synchronize all objects, you can use the `SyncObjects` collection object to select specific objects. For more information, see [NameSpace.SyncObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.syncobjects).

Comment: The send mail immediately is set to 1, so it should be good.  The mail is getting sent with no errors on the VBA side, it just isnt going out until I manually open Outlook on the one PC.

Comment: Seems like Outlook is closed too soon. Try to call the `SendAndReceive` method and wait the SyncEnd event before closing Outlook.